# Trying to send Http response to the frontend before method logic happens

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous, file-upload

What I am trying to accomplish is I have a controller that gets accessed from a frontend (Angular). The users uploads an array of images from the frontend and those images are sent and processed through the backend (Spring Boot). Before the images are processed, I would like to send a response (200) to the frontend so the user does not have to wait for the images to be processed. The code looks like so:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class SolarController {

    @Autowired
    SolarImageServiceImpl solarImageService;

    @Autowired
    SolarVideoServiceImpl solarVideoService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Submit images")
    @PostMapping(value="/solarImage", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void getUploadImages(@ApiParam(value = "Upload images", required = true) @RequestPart(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "User's LanId", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "lanID") String lanId,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "Site name", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "siteName") String siteName,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "User email", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "userEmail") String userEmail,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "Inspection ID", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "inspectionID") String inspectionID) throws IOException{

        if (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
            this.solarImageService.uploadImages(files, lanId, siteName, userEmail, inspectionID);
        }
```

I have looked at multiple other examples, as in using @Async over the method, using HttpServletResponse, and setting my own responses. But nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Submit images")
    @PostMapping(value="/solarImage", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void getUploadImages(@ApiParam(value = "Upload images", required = true) @RequestPart(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "User's LanId", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "lanID") String lanId,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "Site name", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "siteName") String siteName,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "User email", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "userEmail") String userEmail,
                                             @ApiParam(value = "Inspection ID", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "inspectionID") String inspectionID, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

int code = (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(files)) ? HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
                : HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
        if (code != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            response.sendError(code);
            return;
        }

        PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter();
        response.setStatus(code);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        if (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
            this.solarImageService.uploadImages(files, lanId, siteName, userEmail, inspectionID);
        }
```

Sending the HttpServletResponse first did the trick. Annotating the method with @Async did not work.